# Sync Gitlab Code to cPanel (through some script etc.) without installing Git in server

Tags: git, gitlab, cpanel

We have 5 people working on a project in our company. Everyone syncs their respective code to Gitlab. Every time we are copying and pasting the contents from local machine/Gitlab to production server to make our application work. We wish to sync Gitlab code to our cPanel server without installing Git on cPanel server.

Is this possible?

What we want is that as soon as we wish to sync our Gitlab code with cPanel server code, some script or some privilege should be given so that the updated Gitlab code updates the code on the cPanel server.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "copying and pasting" to production server? Aside from that sounding very risky, how do you do that? Do you open the cPanel web app and edit files individually?

Comment: we are not editing single file each time in server, suppose if any changes we do, we create a zip file for those files or respective directories and upload the zip file on server and overwrite the previous files with overwrite option.

Comment: cPanel sometimes supports SFTP, [so see if this works for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714178/syncing-sftp-file-system-with-version-control). You'd have to be able to recreate the whole project locally (i.e. all files rather than just changes ones) but any good deployment strategy requires that.

Comment: Thanks @halfer for your answer. I'm looking into the SFTP thing. BTW, we want to dynamically make the updation. This means that as soon as we change the code in Gitlab, the same changes must be made to the Server. We do not wish to do anything MANUALLY. We want some script to run automatically and carry out the above mentioned process!!

Please tell me if you have an answer for that. Thanks again!!

Comment: Do you have root access to a server somewhere? cPanel is not very flexible because you cannot install the things you need. What I would do is to add a post-commit hook into Gitlab to trigger a new deployment, and to do that you'll probably need a server with Git on it, and SSH keys to your Gitlab repo. It would do a `git pull` on `master` and then create a build from there. Receiving the trigger over HTTP and doing the build probably requires root access, since you'll need to install some things.

Comment: Ultimately, this question is "how to deploy PHP projects to a shared LAMP server", which is very broad, and a book could be written on it.

Comment: That said, you might be able to get away with downloading a zip bundle of the latest `master` from GitLab, to avoid the need to install Git. I know GitHub supports that, not sure about GitLab. That would mean you could write a simple deployment script and add that to your cPanel itself, but it is still not plug and play.

Comment: Thanks @halfer for your answer. Yes we have root access, but im unable to understand what you have written in your comment above

 "What I would do is to add a post-commit hook .......... " 

Can u please explain the steps to be carried out in simpler words?  
Thank you for your time!!

Comment: If we do carry out the installation of Git on cPanel server and use the SSH keys and related stuff and do the `git pull` from the master will there not be any **merge** conflicts on the cPanel server Git?

Comment: No, there should never be merge conflicts on `master` - if you do, you're using Git wrongly. Resolve merge conflicts on a branch, and don't merge them down until they are resolved. For post commit hooks, [see here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=gitlab+post+commit+hook) - it is a feature to extend Git by allowing custom software to react to repository events. A step by step answer would require a book, and thus is far too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Git is automatically provided by the cPanel system to end users. They should already be able to use git.

Comment: Thanks @JPerkSter
We dont wish to use GIT from cPanel, we wish to run some script which will automatically transfer the updated code on GitLab into the preset cPanel server files without any conflicts.

Is that possible ? As of now using git in cPanel is our last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can do only two commands in cPanel such as `git pull` and `git push`

Based on this documentation [cPanel](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/Guide+to+Git+-+How+to+Set+Up+Deployment#cf571087b13b40af82670a95c459d917)

Create the .cpanel.yml file with following code

```
---
deployment:
 tasks:
 - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/
 - /bin/cp index.html $DEPLOYPATH
 - /bin/cp style.css $DEPLOYPATH
```

Add the cPanel-managed repository as a remote.

```
git remote add origin URL
```

Push changes to the cPanel-managed repository.

```
git push -u origin HEAD
```